# error in sudo apt-get update ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I get this error when I want to get the updates

```
ubosi@ubosi-HP-ZBook-15-G2:/$ sudo apt-get update
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/httb could not be found.
```

I have done a typo when installing something (httb instead of http).
how I change and solve this?

Comment: Although this is answerable as-is (and has been answered), you may be able to get more specific answers by explaining exactly what the typo was, preferably by providing the exact wrong command or commands you ran. The `history` command might help you find them. Another benefit to adding further details is that other people with a similar problem may more easily find this question by searching.

Answer (score 1):

Check the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and check the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Look for the typo in the repo URL.

Answer (score 1):

The `/usr/lib/apt/methods` directory contains a file for each protocol supported by APT, including `http`. If you add a repository but give a wrong protocol name in its URL, then you'll get an error like this.

Since the error message is reporting that the *wrong* protocol name `httb` is not found, the problem is due to an incorrect repository. (If it had said that `http` was not found, then it would suggest a change had accidentally been made to the contents of `/usr/lib/apt/methods` itself.)

So the solution is to correct the repository. You didn't say how you added the repository. But you should be able to fix this either by:

- Opening **Software & Updates** (or Software Sources in old versions of Ubuntu), finding the repository you added, and fixing its URL. Or...
- **Manually checking** in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and in the files inside the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, for the line for your repository.

If you added a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, either manually or with the `add-apt-repository` command, then you will likely know what file it is by the name.

These files are owned by root. To edit one of these files, you must run the editor with `sudo` (or, if it is graphical, `gksudo` or `sudo -H`), or use `sudoedit` or `sudo -e`.

For example, suppose the file you need to change is `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list`. One way to edit is:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo nano -w steam.list
```

This opens it in the [Nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) text editor, which runs in your terminal.